# Accessing variable from void method based on given argument

Tags: apex, email, getter

I need to take variable from my void method based on the given argument when calling the method in another class.

`template = //here I want to take variable "ExpiringContract"`

Below is the code;

```
public class automatedCommunication{

    public OrgWideEmailAddress orgWideMail = [SELECT Id FROM OrgWideEmailAddress];
    public String country = '';

    public Id emailtemplate;
    public Id invPDFattachmemt{get;set;}
    public Attachment attach{get;set;}
    public EmailTemplate template;
    public List<Invoice__c> linv;

    public String senderName = 'Lamudi';
    public String defaultReplyEmailID = 'wecare@lamudi.co.id';
    public String defaultReplyEmailPH = 'wecare@lamudi.com.ph';
    public String defaultReplyEmailMX = 'wecare@lamudi.com.mx';

    public void setEmailTemplate(String count){

         //Template for ID
        if(count == 'ID'){
        List<EmailTemplate> ExpiringContract = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Contract renewal notice ID' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> DueInvoice = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Invoice due reminders ID' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> BlockingOutstanding = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Invoice overdue ID' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> BlockingAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Account has been blocked ID' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> DeactivatingAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Account has been deactivated ID' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> LostWinBack = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'lost win back Id' LIMIT 1];
        }

        //Template for MX
        if(count == 'MX'){
        List<EmailTemplate> ExpiringContract = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: '9. Contract renewal notice' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> DueInvoice = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: '10. Invoice Due Reminder' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> BlockingOutstanding = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: '11. Invoice overdue' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> BlockingAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: '12. Account has been blocked' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> DeactivatingAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: '13. Account has been Deactivated' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> LostWinBack = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: '6. Lost Win Back' LIMIT 1];
        }

        //template for PH
        if(count == 'PH'){
        List<EmailTemplate> ExpiringContract = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'New Renewal Notice' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> DueInvoice = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Invoice Due in 2 Weeks' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> BlockingOutstanding = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Blocking Outstanding' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> BlockingAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Blocking Account' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> DeactivatingAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Deactivated Contract' LIMIT 1];
        List<EmailTemplate> LostWinBack = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Lost Win Back' LIMIT 1];
        }

    }


    public void sendRenewalReminder(String selectCountry){

        country = selectCountry;
        this.setEmailTemplate(country);

/**** Set Template ****/

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();

/**** Set filters and conditions (recipients and criteria -> To:, When?, who?, why?) ****/
        List<Contact> licontact = //QUERY

/**** Start process ****/

        IF(licontact.size() >0){

            /**** Set parameters ****/
            List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
            contacts = Database.query(expiredConQuery);

            FOR(Contact cont : contacts){
                ids.add(cont.Account.Id);
            }
            List<Account> accounts = [SELECT LastRenewalNoticeDate__c FROM Account WHERE Id in: ids];

            /**** Create emails ****/

            FOR(Contact cont : contacts){

                template = //here I want to take variable "ExpiringContract"

                emailtemplate = template.Id;

                mail = createEmailMessage(emailtemplate, cont.Id, cont.AccountId, cont.Account.AccountManager__r.Email, cont.Account.AccountManager__r.isActive, cont.Account.Owner.Email, cont.Account.Owner.isActive, cont.Account.AccountCountry__c); 

                mails.add(mail);

                if(Integer.valueof(Limits.getQueries()) >= 40){
                        break;
                }
            }

            system.debug(mails.size());
            system.debug(mails);

        /**** Send emails ****/
            IF(mails.size() >0){
                Messaging.sendEmail(mails, false);

                /***** updates Account date of last sendout to avoid multiple sendouts ****/
                FOR(Account acc : accounts){
                    acc.LastRenewalNoticeDate__c = system.today();
                }

                update accounts;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check that there is a static method called `get(String)` in `EmailTemplate` class

Comment: Hi Isuru I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: As you are not disclosing your variable declarations, it is hard to understand what each variable holds. Also `EmailTemplate.get ()` would reference a static method on the SObject EmailTemplate. That would not work. And SObject.get (String) returns a String, not an object.

Comment: use [edit] and remove lines of code that are irrelevant to this issue. Are you trying to use the Sobject class `get` method? if so, the arguments are either strings or SObjectFields